# Grub 2 wont show window8

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, bootloader

I installed Ubuntu 14. 04 on my Lenovo ideapad 580 (4GB RAM, 500GB HDD, i3, Windows8 preloaded). I switched from UEFI to legacy mode. Then I had a grub issue and Ubuntu won't load at all. I tried boot repair tool and typed the commands in terminal from various links on internet and *voilà* Ubuntu started loading normally but as it appears maybe it overwrote my Windows boot loader.

Now grub2 shows Ubuntu only not Windows at all. I can enter BIOS and change the boot priorities but making Windows on top won't do any good.
I think boot repair tool has done this.

I do not have any CD. I don't want to loose Ubuntu at all because I have employed a large amount of time messing with it and installing.

Boot repair info link is http://paste.ubuntu.com/7638104/